# Why is there Console.Error() in C#, but no Console.Warning?

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, if we want to output an error to the console, we can simply write:

```
Console.Error.Write("Error!");
```

But when I try to write a warning to the console, I found that there isn't any:

```
Console.Warning.Write("Warning!");
```

Instead, I need to write:

```
WarningException myEx = new WarningException("This is a warning");
Console.Write(myEx.ToString());
```

Why is it designed this way?

Comment: `System.Console` is not really comparable to the web's `console.log`, `console.warn` and `console.error` functions. The names are the same, but everything else is so very different.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Because `Console` is adapting to a much older idiom - where every process has 3 streams associated with it at startup - one standard input stream, one standard output stream, and one standard error stream.

(The standard names here are `Console.In`, `Console.Out` and `Console.Error` are their names in the .NET world, not `stdin`, `stdout` & `stderr` as in C.)

This is no standard warning stream.

Be aware that if you use output redirection when running a console application `>file1.txt` will redirect the standard output to `file1.txt` but an error output will continue to be shown on the console. (You use `2>something` to redirect the standard error output or `2>&1` to redirect it to the same place that standard output is going to)